# Meaning of < > in Python

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

What type of Python data structure is represented by "< >", like this.

```
[<Board 1>, <Board 2>, <Board 3>]
```

I came across this while working with the Flask-SQLAlchemy library for Python3. See code below.

```
class Board(db.Model):

  __tablename__ = 'boards'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True, nullable=False)
  description = db.Column(db.String(256))

  def __init__(id, name, description):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.description = description


tuple_boards = Board.query.all()

print (tuple_boards)
[<Board 1>, <Board 2>, <Board 3>]
```

Comment: That's **not** Python syntax. It's not supposed to be; it's actually used to deliberately *distinguish* that representation from something interpretable. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: Huh? Your question is a little weird. What's displayed when you do `print(obj)` is determined by the `obj`'s `__repr__` (or `__str__`) implementation.

Comment: Does `Board` have a `__repr__` or `__str__` defined? As written that is not valid Python syntax, it might just be a custom representation of that data type

Comment: This is a typical format for an objects representation returned by an overwritten `__repr__` or `__str__` method. It does not represent a special type and the "brackets" have to be put in manually.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a data structure. This is just how Flask-SQLAlchemy represents an instance of your model as a string with [`Model.__repr__`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/c52abbdc972d1619847979057ab6263de01485b7/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py#L148-L154):

```
class Model(object):
    ...

    def __repr__(self):
        identity = inspect(self).identity
        if identity is None:
            pk = "(transient {0})".format(id(self))
        else:
            pk = ', '.join(to_str(value) for value in identity)
        return '<{0} {1}>'.format(type(self).__name__, pk)
```

It's a whole lot more useful than the default `object.__repr__`:

```
In [1]: class Thing(object):
  ...       pass
  ...

In [2]: [Thing(), Thing(), Thing()]
Out[2]:
[<__main__.Thing at 0x10c8826a0>,
 <__main__.Thing at 0x10c8820b8>,
 <__main__.Thing at 0x10c8822e8>]
```

You can put whatever you want in `__repr__`, but it's usually best to unambiguously represent your object as a string:

```
In [4]: class OtherThing(object):
  ...       def __repr__(self):
  ...           return "I'm an arbitrary string"
  ...

In [5]: [OtherThing(), OtherThing()]
Out[5]: [I'm an arbitrary string, I'm an arbitrary string]
```

I've often seen the `<...>` string used for object representations that aren't valid Python code, as many other built-in objects' `__repr__`esentations are valid Python code that reconstructs an equivalent object.

Answer (score 3):

It's not Python syntax, but it is part of the default string representation for objects, e.g.

```
>>> a = object()
>>> a
<object object at 0x1009d10b0>
```

In your case, it looks like the implementers of the library have adopted this convention as well.